# Automorphisms of the field of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Using AC one may prove that there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ field automorphisms of the field $\mathbb{C}$. Certainly, only the identity map is $\mathbb{C}$-linear ($\mathbb{C}$-homogenous) among them but are all these automorphisms $\mathbb{R}$-linear?

Comment: R linearity would force the aut. to preserve R. Hence the only ones are the identity and reflection on the i axis.

Comment: perhaps this mathoverflow question will interest you http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24047/ultrafilters-and-automorphisms-of-the-complex-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An automorphism of $\mathbb C$ must take $i$ into $i$ or $-i$. Thus an automorphism that is $\mathbb R$-linear must be the identity or conjugation.

Comment: Is that mean that all aotumorphisms on C fix R?

Comment: @safellh: Clearly they must fix $\mathbb{Q},$ but may not fix $\mathbb{R}.$